# How can I align two forms side by side?

Tags: html, css

I would like two forms side by side, I currently have one shown here: http://gyazo.com/093efe95337ace40fe633adb88b76c2d. I would like on the right hand side the same form that is on the left.

```css
.comments-section .comment-form {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-pane active" id="company-contact">
  <div class="company-profile company-contact">
    <h3>Create an Account With Us</h3>

    <form class="comment-form">

      <div>

        <div class="left">
          Username:
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <input type="text" required>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="left">
        Email:
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="email" required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="left">
        Password:
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="password" required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

</form>
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Wrap this form in a div, and give it a width, make float left in css. Then put the other form at the left side of it.

Comment: you can use float:left rule for this. Just put both form in a single div and give both same class, and for that class add float: left css rule.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you have to close your form before your first 2 div.

Then you can add a second form just after you closed the first one

You add a class to those 2 form

In you css you add

```
.sideBySideForm{
display: inline-block;
}
```

Hope it helps and sorry for my english :)

Comment: How do you mean close my form before the first 2 divs? So both of the forms I would add <form class="sidebysideForm">? No worries about the English it's fine, I'm just new to CSS. Thanks for the help

Comment: Hi what I mean is, at the end of your code you have :  </div></div></form> and I think that you should close you form before those 2 div , </form></div></div> because you opened the form after those 2 div.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting you input boxes like this:

```
    <h3>Create an Account With Us</h3>

    <form class="comment-form">

        username:<input class="comment-form"  type='text' name='username' id='username'  maxlength="50" placeholder="Username" />

        email:<input class="comment-form"  type='text' name='email' id='email'  maxlength="50" placeholder="email" />

        password:<input class="comment-form"  type='text' name='password' id='password'  maxlength="50" placeholder="password" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to specify what do you mean by

> I would like on the right hand side the same form that is on the left

before going to details, I had a similar problem, and I find that using two successive form in html code doesn't work for me.

For your case, there are two possibilities :

1. If the two forms has the same `action` (php action file) :

Here, you have just to use a single form with duplicated input to have a scheme like this

```
<form action = 'youraction.php'>
    <div class='insameline'> 
        <input >username </input>
        <input >username </input>
    </div>
    <div class='insameline'> 
        <input >email </input>
        <input >email </input>
    </div>
    <div class='insameline'> 
        <input >password </input>
        <input >password </input>
    </div>
</form>
```

and then you can use your propoer styles, or use in addition

```
div.insameline {
    display: inline-block
    margin-block-end: 0.83em;
}
```

You can manipulate `margin-block-end` with great value, to push the second block to the right

2. If you want the same form, but two different actions, your code can be similar to this :

```
<form action = 'youraction.php'>
    <div class='insameline'> 
        <input >username </input>
        <input formaction='yourotheraction.php'>username </input>
    </div>
    <div class='insameline'> 
        <input >email </input>
        <input formaction='yourotheraction.php'>email </input>
    </div>
    <div class='insameline'> 
        <input >password </input>
        <input formaction='yourotheraction.php'>password </input>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="company-contact">
  <div class="company-profile company-contact">
    <h3>Create an Account With Us</h3>

    <form class="comment-form">


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="left">
          Username:
      </div>
            <input type="text" required/>
 </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="left">
        Email:
      </div>
      <input type="email" required/>
  </div>  

  <div class="col-md-4"> 
      <div class="left">
        Password:
      </div>
     <input type="password" required/>
   </div>
</div>
</form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Demo [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75s5uver/1/). It is responsive so when the browser is small it will stack up otherwise it will be horizontal as you wanted.
If you don't want it to be stacked up then better use `col-xs-6` instead of `col-md-6`.